# If $t = \sec x$, solve $t^2 + t - 1 = a$ and find the range of values of $a$

Tags: trigonometry

If $t = \sec x$, solve $t^2 + t - 1 = a$ and find the range of values of $a$

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Complete the square:
$$t^2+t-1=\Bigl(t+\frac12\Bigr)^{\!2}-\frac14-1,$$
so the equation come down to
$$\Bigl(t+\frac12\Bigr)^{\!2}=a+\frac54.$$

*Conditions resulting from* $t=\sec x$:

As the range of $\sec x$ is $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)$, the range of $t+\frac12$ is $\bigl(-\infty,-\frac12\bigr]\cup\bigl[\frac32,+\infty\bigr)$, so that squaringwe obtain the condition 
$$a+\frac 54\ge\frac14.$$

Comment: But if $t=\sec x, t+\dfrac12\ne0$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I didn't include in my hint  the constraints resulting from $t$ being a sec. Do you think I should?

Answer (score 1):

$$t^2-t-(a+1)=0$$
Then Quadratic Formula
$$t=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4a+4}}{2}=\frac 12\pm\frac 12\sqrt{4a+5}$$

Answer (score 0):

since,

$\sec(x)\in (-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty) $

$t\notin(-1,1)$

$ f(t) = t^2+t-1,\\ f'= 2t-1 = 0 \quad at \quad t=-1/2\\f(-1)=-1,\ f(-1/2)=-5/4,\ f(1)=1$

if you look at the graph of f(t), you will find:
$ \quad a\in[-1,\infty)$